# FETCH_ASSOC PDO Continuously Looping

Tags: php, sql, pdo, while-loop

I'm new to PDO and I am converting to it from MySQLi due to recent issues I've been having with my web space.

I am trying to use FETCH_ASSOC to loop through results to get the individual records produced by my query, however, the loop is never ending and continuously repeats the first record in the results over and over again. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$Request = databaseManager::getDB()->prepareSQL("SELECT Username, 2Wins, 2Loses, (2Wins/(2Wins+2Loses))*100 as WinRate FROM tblUsers ORDER BY 4 DESC"); 
//$LstResults = $Request->fetchAll();

while($LstResults = $Request->fetchArray()){
    if($LstResults["WinRate"] >= 50){ ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $LstResults["Username"]; ?></td>                                 
        <td>
            <div class="progress progress-xs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: <?php echo $LstResults["WinRate"]; ?>%"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><span class="badge bg-green"><?php echo intval($LstResults["WinRate"]); ?></span></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } 
} ?>
```

**Class**

```
class databaseManager{
    protected $dbHND;
    protected $currentSQLStatement;
    protected $bind;

    private $StrDBHost='localhost';
    private $StrDBPort = "3306";
    private $StrDBUser='thomassm_sqlogin';
    private $StrDBPass='password';
    private $StrDBName='thomassm_CadetPortal';

    public function __construct(){
        if ($this->dbHND = new PDO ('mysql:host=' . $this->StrDBHost . ';dbname=' . $this->StrDBName . ';port=' . $this->StrDBPort, $this->StrDBUser, $this->StrDBPass)){
            $this->bind = null;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    static public function getDB(){
        $tmpInstance = new self ();
        return $tmpInstance;
    }

    public function prepareSQL($sqlQueryString = null){
        if ($sqlQueryString === null){
            $this->currentSQLStatement === false;
            return false;
        }
        elseif (is_array ( $sqlQueryString )){
            if ($this->currentSQLStatement = $this->dbHND->prepare ( $sqlQueryString [0] )){
                $this->bind = $sqlQueryString [1];
                return $this;
            }
            else{
                throw new \Exception ( "Could not prepare SQL Statement, " . print_r ( $this->dbHND->errorInfo () ) );
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            if ($this->currentSQLStatement = $this->dbHND->prepare ( $sqlQueryString )){
                return $this;
            }
            else{
                throw new \Exception ( "Could not prepare SQL Statement, " . print_r ( $this->dbHND->errorInfo () ) );
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public function fetchArray(){
        if (! $this->currentSQLStatement){
            return false;
        }
        elseif ($this->bind != null){
            $this->currentSQLStatement->execute ( $this->bind );
            return $this->currentSQLStatement->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
        }
        else{
            $this->currentSQLStatement->execute ();
            return $this->currentSQLStatement->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
        }
    }

public function fetchAll(){
    if (! $this->currentSQLStatement){
        return false;
    }
    elseif ($this->bind != null){
        $this->currentSQLStatement->execute ( $this->bind );
        return $this->currentSQLStatement->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    }
    else{
        $this->currentSQLStatement->execute ();
        return $this->currentSQLStatement->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You execute before every fetch, so you start at the beginning every time.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware should I remove execute call then from the class and always go `...->execute()->fetchArray();` in the places I have used it before?

Comment: You only need to execute a query once, and then you can fetch all the rows. I would put the execute in your `prepareSQL()` method, and call that method `prepareAndExecuteSQL()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As KIKO Software said in the comments to the questions, I need to only run execute once otherwise it will reset the count of the loop. I have removed the executing from the fetchArray code and now call it before calling fetchArray, like so:

```
public function fetchArray(){
    if (! $this->currentSQLStatement){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return $this->currentSQLStatement->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    }
}
```